# Passing data via instance variable from the controller to the view, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write my first custom controller action and am running into a NoMethodError.

The scenario: PostsController, with the standard 7 actions scaffolding generates.

I want the index page to show a single post instead of displaying a list of them. Each post has a "visible" checkbox. I created a `named_scope` called `visible` in the Post model with:

```
named_scope :visible, :conditions => ["visible =?", true]
```

and applied it along with .last to the index action in my controller:

```
def index
  @post = Post.visible.last
  (format stuff)
end
```

Edited my index view to remove the iterating over an array part so it just shows `@post.title`, etc. So now my index just displays the last record in the Posts table with True on visible.

I then want to create an all posts archive page, that shows all of them regardless of visibility, so I created a new controller action:

(*edited for clarity*)

```
def archives
  render :layout => 'posts'
  @posts = Post.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render :xml => @posts }
  end
end
```

created a new named route:

```
map.archives 'posts/archives', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'archives'
```

and a view named archives.html.erb underneath views/posts.

Archives.html.erb looks exactly like the standard index.html.erb template that scaffolding creates, with a

```
<% for post in @posts %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h post.title %></td>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

When I view this page in my browser, I get an error of

**NoMethodError in Posts#archives**

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it, you might have expected an isntance of Array, the error occurred while evaluating nil.each,

pointing to the line in the view (app/views/posts/archives.html.erb) that says

```
<% for post in @posts %>
```

so my understanding is that the data from the instance variable in the controller action `archives` isn't passing into the view, so instead of an array of posts, I've got nil. I'm looking for a reason why, and what it is I'm doing wrong.

(Of course, if I put

```
<% @posts = Post.find(:all) %>
```

before the

```
<% for post in @posts %>
```

in the view, then it works just fine, but I know this is not what I should do.

All help, links to tutorials to straighten me out, etc is much appreciated.

(I'm doubtful it matters with something this simple, but I'm using Rails 2.2.2 and Ruby 1.8.6.)

Comment: It's hard to tell from your snippets. Could you add the code for the Controller and the View at the bottom of your question?

Comment: At least fill out the controller action so that we can make sure nothing is happening there that accidentally is wiping @posts.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I narrowed down the problem to a bit I forgot to include (of course, sorry)—I want to render using a different layout for this specific action (archives), so I have a `render :layout => 'archives'`, with an archives.html.erb file in /views/layouts.

If I remove that line, then I don't get the error. I've also tried `render :action => 'archives', :layout => 'archives'`. Isn't that the correct way to assign a specific layout to a controller action?

Comment: It seems if I comment out the respond_to format block and move the render :layout => "archives" line to the bottom of the action, then the template renders correctly. I'm confused on why that is the only way this works though, and why the respond_to format block is causing the conflict. Thanks for any insight, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => 'posts' }
    format.xml { render :xml => @posts }
  end
end
```

@posts was not recognized by the view because it was instantiated after you rendered the view.
'render' should be the last executed line in an action.